# Only allow some characters with grep?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I would like to check a string, so it only contains the characters `0-9 a-z -`.

When I do

```
regex='[-a-z0-9]*'
string='abcd!'
if [[ $string =~ $regex ]]
then 
    echo "valid"
else
    echo "not valid"
fi
```

it outputs `valid`, where I would have expected `not valid` because `$string` contains a `!`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this: `regex='^[-a-z0-9]*$'`. It will force the complete line to match this class. Otherwise, only a single match, or no match at all (due to `*`) will return valid. `^...$` says the string starts and ends without anything that fails to match.

Comment: Depending on the constraints, change the `*` to `+`, if you want to disallow empty strings as well.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add boundaries for this regex to work.

'[-a-z0-9]*' says: match these characters 0 or more times anywhere in the string.

So adding start and end of line characters to the regex will do what you are looking for:

```
regex='^[-a-z0-9]*$'
```

The next step is to limit the number of occurrences of the '-' to only once. Can the dash charcter occur at the start or at the end of the string? If not try:

```
regex='^[a-z0-9]*-?[a-z0-9]*$'
```

Hope this helps.